# How to show custom bike image on map with current location update

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit, core-location

I want to show bike / car image on map with rotation on the direction that user follows. How it can be achieve with Map Kit and Core Location frameworks ?

Comment: have you tried anything or we need to do this task for you?

Comment: I got new latitude and longitude with didUpdateToLocation method of CLLocation, but what to do next ?

Comment: Add annotation on that point and use method /; viewForAnnotiation to add image on it .

Comment: Is viewForAnnotiation is delegate/datasource method ? How to call delegate method of didUpdateToLocation from another delegate method viewForAnnotiation ?